# React component rendering on server-side, but client-side does not take over

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ejs, isomorphic-javascript

I have an EJS view which is served up to a client:

### index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="reactApp">
            <%- reactContent %>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="__res__/client/main.bundle.js" />
</html>
```

`main.bundle.js` is the bundle that I create using browserify:

### gulpfile.js (partial)

```
function bundle(filename) {
    var bundler = browserify('./app/client/' + filename + '.js');

    bundler.transform(babelify);
    bundler.transform(reactify);

    return bundler.bundle()
        .pipe(source(filename + '.bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/client'));
}
```

And the client is ultimately served this code:

### main.js (bundled into main.bundle.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Login} from './auth/login.react';

React.render(React.createElement(Login), document.getElementById('reactApp'));
alert('hi');
```

However, even though the browser requests and recieves the `main.bundle.js` script, the client does not run the `alert('hi');` line, which leads me to believe that the `React.render` line does not work either. I can affirm that Javascript is enabled, and my browser is the latest version of Chrome. My react component (`Login`) is as follows:

### login.react.js

```
import React from 'react';

export class Login extends React.Component
{
    handleClick() {
        alert('Hello!');
    }

    render() {
        console.log('rendered');
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>This is a React component</button>
        );
    }
}
```

So, very simple. However, none of the alerts that you see in the code is ever run. The `console.log('rendered');` line is never run on the server, but when I check the source code for my page, I get:

### HTML output of my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="reactApp">
            <button data-reactid=".2fqdv331erk" data-react-checksum="436409093">Lel fuck u</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="__res__/client/main.bundle.js" />
</html>
```

Which means that the server correctly renders my react component, but why does the client script not work? The `handleClick` function never runs, my `console.log` lines never run, and neither does the `alert` lines. What is happening? The reactid and checksum are rendered correctly, shouldn't it be working? Shouldn't the React code on the client-side be smart enough to find the component and run correctly?

Comment: If even the `alert` isn't running then your main.js simply can't be being bundled properly and/or executed properly.

Comment: What is wrong with my bundle code then?

Comment: Use the browsers network/source tools to check the source that is being returned to the client. Also check for console errors.

Comment: No errors, lemme work through this for awhile

Comment: @WiredPrairie The alert code is there, uglified or not. http://i.imgur.com/aeUK4DV.png?2

Comment: @Kenny I'd remove everything from `main.js` except the alert. If it still doesn't work, there's likely something wrong with the gulp/browserify config.

Comment: @BinaryMuse yea, it fails, I'll look into it, but what is going on? It looks like alert gets wrapped into a function that is never called. http://i.imgur.com/MmfVRNG.png?1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.ejs, adding a closing element to your script tag should fix the issue: `<script src="__res__/client/main.bundle.js"></script>`

On a separate note, in my testing, I was getting an error in login.react.js when loading the page until I added **default** to the export line: `export default class Login extends React.Component`. Not sure if you will need to do the same.

Comment: This was the problem, however, I don't get any issues when I import with `{Login}`.